# Emacs shell can't find ruby gems -- e.g., Could not find RubyGem haml (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)

Tags: ruby, emacs, rubygems, rvm

My emacs shell can't load any of my installed ruby gems.  I'm getting a Gem::LoadError when trying to execute any installed gem from emacs but it works from Terminal.  Here's all the information I've reviewed in my environment.  Thanks for any help!

- Running Emacs.app on my Mac OSX Snow
  Leopard (from [emacsformacosx](http://emacsformacosx.com/)
  using universal dmg).
- Installed RVM, then used RVM to
  install Ruby 1.9.2 and 1.8.7.
- Installed several gems, including
  rails and haml.
- Did not use root for these installs.

From Terminal (bash), I'm able to run the gems (e.g., haml somepage.haml or rails create someapp)

In emacs, I've set the shell (bash) path to load the same as the terminal shell (via ~/.MacOSX/application.plist).

`echo $PATH` returns the same result from terminal and emacs

I can run IRB and rvm from emacs shell.

Running `gem list` from emacs shell shows I have haml (3.1.2, 3.1.1) installed.
Running: `which rvm, which gem, which haml` #all return the same path in both Terminal and Emacs

When I try to execute a gem (e.g., haml), I get the following:

> /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:900:in
>   `report_activate_error': Could not
>   find RubyGem haml (>= 0)
>   (Gem::LoadError)  from
>   /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:248:in`
>   activate'    from
>   /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1276:in
>   `gem'     from
>   /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/haml:18:in`
>   '

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your `GEM_HOME` environment variable is set properly or you may have trouble. `rvm` does move this from the usual location, and `bundler` can move it again.

This is particularly important if you're loading gems from your home directory because they are managed by `rvm`.

Comment: Thanks, tadman.  Your suggestion sent me in the right direction.  I had explicitly set the gem_home and gem_path in rvm but these weren't being picked up in emacs.  I tried, unsuccessfully, to set the gem envs in emacs but noticed that changing rubies in rvm wasn't picked up in emacs.  I ended up using rvm.el (https://github.com/senny/rvm.el) via the ELPA and activating the current ruby -- worked!  Hope that helps anyone else who's struggling.